# Resize template image from skin folder Magento

Tags: magento

I want to display resized image from \skin\frontend\\default\images location. Right now i am using simple
        `<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/free_shipping.png')?>" alt="Free Shipping" />`
Can anyobdy tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default out the box magento only allow you to resize catalog image, but you could create your own functionality to resize  skin images. See http://magedev.com/2009/08/16/magento-image-manipulation/

```
$fileName = 'skin\frontend\default\default\images\media\col_left_callout.jpg';

$image = new Varien_Image($fileName);

// this function accepts integer, hexadecimal format is more convenient for me
$image->setImageBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF);

$image->resize(250);


// this will generate proper headers for transformed image so don't use this method if you plan to display any other content
$image->display();

// Magento will attempt to create missing directories
$image->save('media/myimages/myTransformedImage.jpg');
```

Also see

- http://subesh.com.np/2009/11/image-resize-magento-cache-resized-image/